# Solving $Ax=0$ for non-negative $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

This seems like a fairly elementary problem but I have not been able to find an a suitable way  to this problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The problem is simple. I have a large matrix and would like to find a vector in its nullspace such that the components are greater than equal to zero, i.e., solve:

$$\begin{align} A\mathbf{x} &= 0 \\ \text{    subject to: } x_i &\geq 0 \end{align}$$

It is possible to find a basis for the nullspace of $A$ numerically, but this just leads to a system of linear inequalities which I am unsure how to solve:
$$ B\mathbf{c} \geq 0 $$
where the columns of $B$ are the nullspace basis vectors. If I can solve this for $\mathbf{c}$ then the solution to the previous problem is just $\mathbf{x} = B \mathbf{c}$

Comment: Non-negative, my mistake. It's for numerical work so it's unlikely to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this as a linear programming problem, e.g.:

maximize $\sum_i x_i$

subject to $Ax = 0$

all $0 \le x_i \le 1$

The upper bounds are to make the problem bounded.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid linear programming for performance reasons but it looks like I have no other option.